# Cron job: PHP Looping script by URL parameter

Tags: php, apache, cron

I have a php file (insert-album.php) that will get some external json data, and will insert it into a MYSQL Database. There is kind of a lot of data for each record ID. So it redirects to it self but get the next record via URL parameter.  (insert-album.php?id=2) etc.

Can i set this up as a **cron job** that will just continue to loop through the **records** via URL parameter? and update/add records to my database?

Comment: Please post some code for more clarity